# Angular router cookie path

Tags: angular, cookies, angular-router

I have an issue not being able to retrieve cookie when using path in an angular router application. I have a default route redirecting to "/admin/compa" where 2 cookies are being set: first with a path of "/" and the other to "/admin". I am console logging document.cookie right after.

When I go the my default route then I am being redirected to "/admin/compa" but I only see the first cookie. If I enter "/admin/compa" in my browser then I get to see both cookies.

I don't know how I could get the "/admin" cookie to show despite going to the default route. Here is a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-md9o7g).

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?